# Create files from one column of a csv. And write data from the other column to thos files

Tags: bash, csv

I have a csv file (xyz.csv) contains hostnames and IPs.
e.g.:

```
HOSTNAME;IP;GW
device1;ip1;gw1
device2;ip2;gw2
```

I want to create files named with data from the column1 and those files contain data from column2.
So, file "device1" contain ip1 and gw1(the order dose matter) and so on.

Expected output:

```
cat device1

ip1
gw1

cat device2

ip2
gw2
```

Comment: is it possible for a hostname to show up more than once in the file and if so do you create just one file or do you create a separate file for each (and if 'separate file' then what additional string is added to make the filename unique)?

Comment: Should each of the output files include the header row `HOSTNAME;IP` or not? Does the order of the lines in each output fie matter (assuming you can have multiple lines per `HOSTNAME`)? Please [edit] your question to show more truly representative sample input and add the currently missing expected output.

Comment: The algorithm is so easy: Iterate the rows, split the row to to get the device and ip as variables, use that variables to create the text and its content

Comment: The hosnames are unique, the header row shouldn't be contained in the file.
If I have more than one line, then dose the order matter.
The answer from Fravadona worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the great [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) to run

```bash
# create output folder
mkdir -p ./output
# extract in it one file for each HOSTNAME
mlr --csv --fs ";" --from input.csv put -q 'tee > "./output/".$HOSTNAME.".csv", $*'

mlr -I --headerless-csv-output  --csv --ifs ";"  cut -x -f HOSTNAME then reshape -r "." -o i,v then cut -f v ./output/*.csv
```

and get

```bash
cat ./output/device1.csv

ip1
gw1

cat ./output/device2.csv

ip2
gw2
```

Comment: Great, it works as expected!
as Fravadona described in comment works as well
{ read; while IFS='...' read -r ... ... ; do printf '%s\n' "$..." > "$..."; done; } < xyz.csv

Comment: @Tom did you remove the flag? Why? Does it not work?

Comment: @Tom you have edited your question. And I have edited my answer